# Where does locale variable comes from in Rails view and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a newly created rails app (using rails 4.0.3). I notice that there is a `locale` variable available in controller & view but not in the model. I am wondering where does it comes from. Thanks. Its value seems to be the browser preferred language.

Comment: Are you using a system of "internationalisation", such as I18n?  (i think rails may come with I18n by default now) - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

Locale Get and set the current locale. It's a public attribute of the I18n library.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api